# ASP.NET Repeater item in a subclass

Tags: asp.net, repeater

Here's how I pull a field from my object:

However, how do I pull a field if it's in a subclass (Customer.ContactInfo.Name)?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you know that the DataItem is a certain type (let's say you know it's a CustomerInfo type), you can do this:

```
<%# ((CustomerInfo) Container.DataItem).ContactInfo.Name %>
```

As a bonus, it's somewhat quicker than using DataBinder.Eval, because you avoid all the overhead of reflection.

Answer (score 3):

Try...

```
<%#((Customer)Container.DataItem).ContactInfo.Name%>
```

Comment: Got beaten to it again. And with better whitespacing, too. =)

Comment: @Keltex Likewise. +1 on the Eval. People should really stop using it even for a single level bind.

Answer (score 1):

If the repeater is being bound to a collection of Customer objects then to grab the name from the contact info: